# How to satisfy the absorbing boundary condition here as method of images fails?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have a function $f(x,t)$ given by:
$$f(x,t)=\cases{0 , & $x<0$\\ f_1(x,t) , & $0<x<x_c$ \\ 0, & $x>x_c$}$$
of which $f_1(x)$ satisfies the following partial differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial t}=c\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}+D\frac{\partial^2f_1}{\partial x^2}$$

where $c,D$ are constants with boundary conditions:

1. $f_1(x,0)=\delta(x-x_0)$
2. $f_1(0,t)=0$
3. $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}=\sigma(t) \,\,\,\,\, \text{at} \,\,\, x=x_c$

Now to solve this differential equation, I took the fourier transform of both sides of the differential equation and got
$$\frac{dF}{dt}=ickF-Dk^2F$$
Solving this and then going for fourier inversion, I finally got
$$f_1(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}\exp\left[-\frac{(x-x_0-ct)^2}{4Dt}\right]$$

But this does not satisfy the boundary conditions $2$ and $3$. And method of images also does not work here. What to do to correct this?